# Latin names of Cambridge terms

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, academic-latin

The academic year at the University Cambridge consists of three terms: Michaelmas, Lent and Easter.
For more details, consult [the term date pages of the university](https://www.cam.ac.uk/about-the-university/term-dates-and-calendars).
What are these terms called in Latin?
I would prefer to see actual use examples, newer or older.
I assume that Cambridge has sufficient history in using Latin that Latin versions of the names do exist.

Comment: I see no alternative to them comming from Christian liturgy, thus Lent-->Quadragessima, Easter-->Pascha/tempus paschale. The connection is more _loose_ with Michaelmas ([ethymologically](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Michaelmas), Mass of [Saint] Michael), since it corresponds to a single day: Festus Sancti Michaelis. The names seem to be previous to the Reformation. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelmas_term).

Comment: @Rafael, I agree now that they probably have Christian origin. Before googling in preparation of this question I didn't know that Lent and Michaelmas meant something. However, it is not clear what the exact Latin names are, and how one might say "I took an algebra class in the Michaelmas/Lent/Easter term" in Latin.

Comment: In the _societas christiana_ of the High Middle Ages it was very common to divide the year (and day) according to liturgy. Education was broadly in charge of monks and priests. While I write this, @fdb posted an answer regarding the word for _term_ which I didn't know (I would have chosen something like bimensis in the lack of a sourced expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These phrases come from English Law Latin, which divides the Legal Year into four quarters: Terminus Paschae, Terminus Trinitatis, Terminus Sancti Michaelis, Terminus Sancti Hilarii.

See this: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DeQYXYMBtwgC&pg=PA976&lpg=PA976&dq=%22Terminus+trinitatis%22&source=bl&ots=CV2kk-794L&sig=1yXPeJLBn4AECOytRjeUsdm7c1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjripmNn-nOAhUkAsAKHZviAp0Q6AEIJDAD#v=onepage&q=%22Terminus%20trinitatis%22&f=false

Comment: Great! Can you add any sources?

Comment: Just to be sure: Would Lent be called *Terminus Sancti Hilarii*? The connection to the English version is much less obvious than for the other two.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. Yes exactly. In what we in Cambridge call “the other place” (i.e., Oxford) the three academic terms are called Michaelmas, Hilary, Trinity.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It seems that the choice for names is not uniform and universal: as you see in the source, they connect T. S. Hilarii to a _Hilary Term_, while wikipedia has separate articles for [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_term) and [Lent Term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lent_term)

Comment: @fdb, excellent, thank you! (I'm much more familiar with Cambridge than the other place, so the Oxford term names were news to me.)